# Material optimization in Unity3d

Tags: unity

In my 2d game I need a road. And here is two ways, how can I make it.

I can make it using **a lot of quads** with size 1*1, or for each specific area (they all have different length) I can use **big quads** with size 1*10, 1*5, etc.

In the **Mipmaps** view both variants doesn't looks good, because:

- in the 1st case it is a lot of poligons
- in the 2nd case texture on the material are stretched (but have only 2 polygons). Although each quad need its own material, because I can't use the same material for quad 1*10 and quad 1*20 - they are have different stretched settings.

What is the best way here for optimization?

[image]

Settings for second case:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate your quads in "chunks" then group the chunks in to a "World" parent object.
Assign a single material to the parent then pass that down to the children.

The children can then share a single material.

If your doing what I think your doing (making a tile based map for your game) you may want to build a sprite containing all the tile textures then each tile will have uv coords that map to part of the material main texture.

Effectively this results in ...

1. less mesh objects
2. less draw calls
3. more opportunity for the engine to determine if it can save on draw calls with batching on its own

experimenting with chunk sizing may help you determine some interesting answers to how your code performs.

Comment: What do you mean under "World" parent object"? When I put my "chunks" (like in my first example) inside parent object, which is quad too, and  apply material to that parent quad, then it applies only for that, but not for children.

Comment: Basically you are creating a material for each tile when all you need is 1 material for all tiles. My answer gives you that by allowing you to build a mesh with lots of tiles then for each vertex (tile corner) you can specify the texture part to use of that 1 shared material.